# TimeZone Brazil of Java Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, timezone, dst

I'm working in a application that uses Java 8, Maven and Spring. Since 2019, the DayLight Saving Time was abolished in Brazil. Since then, when i run the application, still getting the time like there was DST.

I have used the tzupdate and ziupdate to fix it, but had no effect. Even the logs when I run the application are offset by 1 hour.

The application always goes up with the local time of the operating system, which works for other timezones but not for Brazil.

Anyone knows how to fix that?

EDIT:

Updating the version of java I noticed something. When I run the application on a Windows terminal, the logs come out with a correct time. When I use the visual studio code terminal to use the debug, it runs with the offset time of one. Maybe is a configuration of VS Code

Comment: Did you upgrade to the latest version of Java 8? Which version do you have?

Comment: From https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html: "Brazil no longer observes DST." in JRE 8u231

Comment: Updating the version of java I noticed something. When I run the application on a Windows terminal, the logs come out with a correct time. When I use the visual studio code terminal to use the debug, it runs with the offset time of one. Maybe is a configuration of VS Code

Comment: Reminder: Besides updating your JVM's [`tzdata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), remember to update your host operating systems, and database systems such as Postgres that maintain their own copy of tzdata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try open the settings.json from VScode and check if there is a java.home attribute pointing to an older version of jdk

Comment: FYI, some IDEs such as IntelliJ embed a JVM within itself (within the IDE app) for running the app rather than relying on your externally installed JVM. That JVM within the app may need its JVM updated with the latest [`tzdata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).